# Nested jquery "if else if" crashes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this block of javascript which is working just fine.

```
        $('#<%=Button_PayFees.ClientID%>').click(function (evt) {
            var valuefirstname = $('#<%=TextBox_FirstName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuelastname = $('#<%=TextBox_LastName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valueaddress = $('#<%=TextBox_Address.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuecity = $('#<%=TextBox_City.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuestate = $('#<%=Dropdownlist_States.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuezipcode = $('#<%=TextBox_ZipCode.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuephone = $('#<%=TextBox_Phone.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valueEmail = $('#<%=TextBox_EmailAddress.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuecreditcard = $('#<%=DropDownList_CreditCard.ClientID%>').val();
            var valuecreditcardnumber = $('#<%=TextBox_CreditCard.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuecsvcode = $('#<%=TextBox_CSVCode.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();

            var valueparticipantfirstname = $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantFirstName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valueparticipantlastname = $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantLastName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valueTeamName = $("#<%=DropDownList_CheerLevel.ClientID%>").find("option:selected").text();
            var valueOrganization = $('#<%=TextBox_Organization.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();

            var valuedeliveryfirstname = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryFirstName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliverylastname = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryLastName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliveryaddress = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryAddress.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliverycity = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryCity.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliverystate = $('#<%=DropDownList_DeliveryStates.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliveryzipcode = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryZipCode.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();


            if(valueparticipantfirstname == '' ){
                alert('Participant firstname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantFirstName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valueparticipantlastname == ''){
                alert('Participant lastname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantLastName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valueOrganization == '') {
                alert('Organization is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_Organization.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valueTeamName == 'Select Cheer Level') {
                alert('Select Cheer Level from the drop down list.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=DropDownList_CheerLevel.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (selection == 'Select DVD Option') {
                alert('Please select a DVD option from the drop down list.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=DropDownList_Options.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valuefirstname == '') {
                alert('Firstname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_FirstName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valuelastname == ''){
                alert('Lastname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_LastName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valueaddress == '') {
                alert('Address is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_Address.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuecity == '') {
                alert('City is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_City.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuestate == 'SELECT STATE') {
                alert('Select state from the drop down list.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=DropDownList_States.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuezipcode == '') {
                alert('Zip code is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_ZipCode.ClientID%>').focus();

            }
            else if(valuephone == '') {
                alert('Phone is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_Phone.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valueEmail == '') {
                alert('Email Address is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_EmailAddress.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuecreditcard == 'SELECT CARD TYPE') {
                alert('Select credit card type from the drop down list.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=DropDownList_CreditCard.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuecreditcardnumber == '') {
                alert('Enter credit card number.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_CreditCard.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuecsvcode == '') {
                alert('Enter credit card ID code.');
                $('#<%=TextBox_CSVCode.ClientID%>').focus();
                evt.preventDefault();
            }
    });
```

When I change it to add checks for delivery information when a checkbox is checked it crashes ... no idea why as I'm not getting any feed back from the site.  The code that crashes is (note the nested else if):

```
        $('#<%=Button_PayFees.ClientID%>').click(function (evt) {
            var valuefirstname = $('#<%=TextBox_FirstName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuelastname = $('#<%=TextBox_LastName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valueaddress = $('#<%=TextBox_Address.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuecity = $('#<%=TextBox_City.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuestate = $('#<%=Dropdownlist_States.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuezipcode = $('#<%=TextBox_ZipCode.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuephone = $('#<%=TextBox_Phone.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valueEmail = $('#<%=TextBox_EmailAddress.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuecreditcard = $('#<%=DropDownList_CreditCard.ClientID%>').val();
            var valuecreditcardnumber = $('#<%=TextBox_CreditCard.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuecsvcode = $('#<%=TextBox_CSVCode.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();

            var valueparticipantfirstname = $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantFirstName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valueparticipantlastname = $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantLastName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valueTeamName = $("#<%=DropDownList_CheerLevel.ClientID%>").find("option:selected").text();
            var valueOrganization = $('#<%=TextBox_Organization.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();

            var valuedeliveryfirstname = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryFirstName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliverylastname = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryLastName.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliveryaddress = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryAddress.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliverycity = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryCity.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliverystate = $('#<%=DropDownList_DeliveryStates.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
            var valuedeliveryzipcode = $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryZipCode.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();


            if(valueparticipantfirstname == '' ){
                alert('Participant firstname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantFirstName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valueparticipantlastname == ''){
                alert('Participant lastname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantLastName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valueOrganization == '') {
                alert('Organization is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_Organization.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valueTeamName == 'Select Cheer Level') {
                alert('Select Cheer Level from the drop down list.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=DropDownList_CheerLevel.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (selection == 'Select DVD Option') {
                alert('Please select a DVD option from the drop down list.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=DropDownList_Options.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valuefirstname == '') {
                alert('Firstname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_FirstName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if (valuelastname == ''){
                alert('Lastname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_LastName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valueaddress == '') {
                alert('Address is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_Address.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuecity == '') {
                alert('City is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_City.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuestate == 'SELECT STATE') {
                alert('Select state from the drop down list.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=DropDownList_States.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuezipcode == '') {
                alert('Zip code is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_ZipCode.ClientID%>').focus();

            }
            else if(valuephone == '') {
                alert('Phone is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_Phone.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valueEmail == '') {
                alert('Email Address is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_EmailAddress.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if($('#<%= Checkbox_Delivery.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) {
                     else if (valuedeliveryfirstname == '') {
                         alert('Please enter the first name of the person the DVD is being delivered to.');
                         evt.preventDefault();
                         $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryFirstName.ClientID%>').focus();
                     }
                     else if (valuedeliverylastname == '') {
                         alert('Please enter the last name of the person the DVD is being delivered to.');
                         evt.preventDefault();
                         $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryLastName.ClientID%>').focus();
                     }
                     else if (valuedeliveryaddress == '') {
                         alert('Please enter the delivery Address.');
                         evt.preventDefault();
                         $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryAddress.ClientID%>').focus();
                     }
                     else if (valuedeliverycity == '') {
                         alert('Please enter the delivery city.');
                         evt.preventDefault();
                         $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryCity.ClientID%>').focus();
                     }
                     else if (valuedeliverystate == 'SELECT STATE') {
                         alert('Select the delivery state from the drop down list.');
                         evt.preventDefault();
                         $('#<%=DropDownList_DeliveryStates.ClientID%>').focus();
                     }
                     else if (valuedeliveryzipcode == '') {
                         alert('Please enter the delivery Zip code.');
                         evt.preventDefault();
                         $('#<%=TextBox_DeliveryZipCode.ClientID%>').focus();
                     }
            }
            else if(valuecreditcard == 'SELECT CARD TYPE') {
                alert('Select credit card type from the drop down list.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=DropDownList_CreditCard.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuecreditcardnumber == '') {
                alert('Enter credit card number.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_CreditCard.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            else if(valuecsvcode == '') {
                alert('Enter credit card ID code.');
                $('#<%=TextBox_CSVCode.ClientID%>').focus();
                evt.preventDefault();
            }
    });
```

something in the nested else if causes the code to crash.  I can't see it.

Comment: "Crashes" how, exactly?  What is the error?

Comment: `else if($('#<%= Checkbox_Delivery.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) { if (valuedeliveryfirstname == '') {`

Comment: @danronmoon ah ... knew I was missing something.  Now the code loads and runs but doesn't execute the code below the nested else if, IE the credit card number etc.

Comment: You really shouldn't be validating forms like this, it's bad UX. All failed validations should be shown every time not just the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look right!

```
            else if($('#<%= Checkbox_Delivery.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) {
                     else if (valuedeliveryfirstname == '') {
```

The indented `else if` should just be `if` there is no preceeding `if` inside the block.

```
            else if($('#<%= Checkbox_Delivery.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) {
                     if (valuedeliveryfirstname == '') {
```

Comment: You are correct, but now the else if below that block of code is not executing, IE, the credit card checks..

Comment: I removed the `else` in front of the `if` in the code block under the nested `if else` and that worked.  Why it fell through the rest of the code escapes me but at least I can move on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not be using else if for all the other fields otherwise the if loop will exit when it enters the first matching condition. It should be:

```
            if(valueparticipantfirstname == '' ){
                alert('Participant firstname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantFirstName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            if (valueparticipantlastname == ''){
                alert('Participant lastname is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_ParticipantLastName.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            if (valueOrganization == '') {
                alert('Organization is required.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=TextBox_Organization.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
            if (valueTeamName == 'Select Cheer Level') {
                alert('Select Cheer Level from the drop down list.');
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#<%=DropDownList_CheerLevel.ClientID%>').focus();
            }
    .
    .
    .
```

Also, this code:

```
            else if($('#<%= Checkbox_Delivery.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) {
                     else if (valuedeliveryfirstname == '') {
```

needs to be changed to:

```
            else if($('#<%= Checkbox_Delivery.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) {
                     if (valuedeliveryfirstname == '') {
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Exiting the block is exactly what I need to do.  One check at a time.  There's a reason I need to do it that way which is too time consuming to get into here.